# Exceptions swallowed in event handlers

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

In winforms, using vb.net and .NET 4.0 32bit, I have made a user control with custom events which fired when I click on a control located in the custom control (basically just bubbling events from the underlying control after a bit of processing).

I have this control, let's call it `child`, on a second custom, say `Parent`, control which I load into a tab control on my main form. In parent I do something like this:

```
Public Class Parent : Inherits ParentBase

    Public Sub Child_SnapToObject(byval sender ..., byval e ...) Handles Child.SnapToObject

         ' Do stuff here

    End Sub

    Public Sub Child_ScaleChanged(byval sender ..., byval e ...) Handles Child.ScaleChanged

         ' Do stuff here

    End Sub

End Class
```

The event handlers get executed fine, but any exceptions that occur in them just get swallowed making it a nightmare to debug. This is the case for all events

`Child` is defined in a separate project. I have checked the event handlers which are bubbling through the events from the underlying control and all of those swallow exceptions. On the other hand exceptions get thrown from the constructor.

I can't find anything that suggests that this is normal behviour... Does anybody know if this is a bug or what, and how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be due to the fact that my user control is in a different project. After enabling menu option "Break when exceptions cross appDomain or managed/native boundaries ..." (in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General) the exceptions do not get swallowed anymore.

I think this is supposed to be enabled by default. Since my project is a conversion from a VS2003 project, I assume that the setting got turned off during the conversion.

Comment: It is not enabled by default.  Hard to see what's behind this, there is exception swallowing behavior when you target x86 on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Oh, so it got enabled by default after I enabled it... Is there a reason why it isn't by default? I get all exceptions throwing fine now, so it must have been the cross domain thing, I guess. I read about the 64-bit problem yesterday, but I am working on 32-bit targetting any-cpu, so I don't think that could have been it?